A problem on additive combinatorics in right-ordered groups
In a paper Small doubling in ordered groups: generators and structure  it is proven in Lemma 4 page no. 598 that:
Let $G$ be an ordered group. Let $S$ be a finite subset of $G$ with at least two elements. Let either $ m=$ max $S$ or $m=$ min $S$ and $T= S\setminus\{m\}.$ Then either $\langle S\rangle$ is a 2-generated abelian group, or $|T^2|\leq |S^2|-3. $
They have proven this result using this lemma
Let $G$ be an ordered group. Let $T$  be a non-empty finite subset of $G$
and let $ t$ denote its maximal element max $T$ . Let $x \in G$ be an element satisfying
$x > t.$ If $ yx, xy \in T^2$ for each $y\in T\setminus\{t\}$, then $T\subseteq\langle t, x\rangle. $
The proof is very simple you can find it here in Lemma 3 page no. 595 Small doubling in ordered groups: generators and structure
I am trying to look at this problem in the right-ordered groups. There are a few examples where we see this lemma does not hold for the right-ordered group. But if we take a set with an identity element then  I stated it as follows
Let $S$ be a finite subset of positive elements of a right-ordered group containing identity with at least two elements. Let  $m$ = max $S$  and $A=S\setminus\{m\}.$ Then either $\langle S\rangle$ is an abelian  group, or $|A^2|\leq |S^2|-3.$
I tried to prove it like this:
Let $S=\{e,x_2,\ldots, x_k\}$ and $A=\{e, x_2,\ldots, x_{k-1}\} $ with $e<x_2<\cdots<x_k.$
Suppose $x_ix_j$ be the maximum element of $A^2$ then $x_ix_j<x_kx_j$ therefore $x_kx_j\notin A^2.$
Case1: Consider $x_jx_k,$ if $x_kx_j= x_jx_k\implies x_kx_j<x_k^2.$
Therefore $x_jx_k, x_k^2\notin A^2.$
If $j<k-1,$ then $x_jx_k<x_{k-1}x_k<x_k^2,$ so we are done.
Suppose $j=k-1.$ Therefore we have $x_{k-1}x_k=x_kx_{k-1}.$
Now $S$ is nonabelian so there exist minimum $x_a,x_b$ such that $x_ax_b\neq x_bx_a.$ We claim that $x_kx_a\notin A^2.$ How to show that $x_kx_a\notin A^2.$
Case 2:
If $x_kx_j\neq x_jx_k,$ and $x_kx_j$ is bigger than the maximum element of $A^2.$  How to show that $x_jx_k\notin A^2$?
Now $S$ is nonabelian so there exist minimum $x_a,x_b$ such that $x_ax_b\neq x_bx_a.$ We claim that $x_kx_a\notin A^2.$ How to show that $x_kx_a\notin A^2.$
My guess is either $\{x_kx_j, x_k^2, x_kx_a\}$ or $\{x_kx_j, x_jx_k, x_kx_a\}$ are not in $A^2.$ Since identity is also there in my set how can we use that here?
(  For the ordered group, they have used the lemma which I have mentioned above (2nd lemma.) i.e If all $x_kx_i, x_ix_k\in A^2$ for each $i<k-1$ then $A\subseteq\langle x_{k-1}, x_k\rangle. $
So if we try this lemma in the right-ordered group i.e. If all $x_kx_i, x_ix_k\in A^2$ for each $i<k-1$ what can we say about the structure of $A.$
I have tried with so many examples with the condition $x_kx_i, x_ix_k\in A^2$ for each $i<k-1$ having $x_k$ maximum element of $S.$ I was always getting $A$ to be abelian set so if $A$ is abelian then the result holds. But I couldn't construct any nonabelian set having this property  .)
I tried in this way also:
Since $S$ is nonabelian.  Let $i$ be the maximal integer such that $$A'=\{e, x_2, x_3\cdots, x_{i}\}$$ generates an abelian subgroup. Then \begin{equation}
     1\leq i<k, x_{i+1}\notin C_G(A'), x_{i+1}\notin \langle A'\rangle
\end{equation} and there exists $x_j \in A'$ such that
\begin{equation}
x_{i+1}x_j\neq x_jx_{i+1}.\end{equation}
Let $x_j\in A'$ be the maximal such element of $A'.$ Then \begin{equation}
    x_a\in C_G(x_{i+1}) \text{ for each } x_a\in A'  \text{ satisfying } x_a>x_j.\end{equation} Moreover, we can write that \begin{equation}\label{D'}A'^2\cap (x_{i+1}A'\cup A'x_{i+1})=\emptyset. \end{equation}
Write $$D=\{x_{i+1}, x_{i+2}, \ldots, x_k\}.$$
Suppose $|D|=1.$ Therefore we have $A'=A=\{e, x_2,\ldots , x_{k-1}\}$ abelian. Since $A$ is abelian maximum element of $A$ is $x_{k-1}^2$ because $e<x_2<x_2^2<x_2x_3<\cdots<x_{k-1}^2<x_kx_{k-1}.$ Now if $x_k\in A,$ then $\langle S\rangle $ is abelian. Therefore we have either $\{x_k,x_kx_{k-1}, x_k^2\}$ or $\{x_k, x_{k-1}x_k, x_kx_{k-1}\}$ does not belong to $A^2.$
Suppose $|D|=2$ and let $D=\{x_{i+1}, x_{i+2}\}$ , then $i=k-2.$ Let $D$ is abelian.
Consider $x_kx_{k-2}\notin A'^2$ the only possibility $x_kx_{k-2}\in A^2$ is either $x_kx_{k-2}=x_jx_{k-1}$ where $x_j\in A'^2$ or $x_kx_{k-2}=x_{k-1}^2.$ If $x_kx_{k-2}=x_{k-1}^2,$ then $x_{k-2}x_{k-1}=x_{k-1}x_{k-2},$ a contradiction. How to show that $x_kx_{k-2}=x_jx_{k-1}$ where $x_j\in A'^2$ is also not possible.
How to prove when $D$ is nonabelian.
Can we use induction here like if results holds for $|D|=2,$ then assume for $|D|=k-i-1,$ and prove for $|D|=k-i.$

We can assume all elements belong to a positive cone of a right-ordered group, i.e. $e<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_k.$

Can you recall the definition of a  right-ordered group?

A group G is right-ordered if it can be totally ordered so that for any a, b, c in G, a < b implies that ac < bc.
